# Python IDLE won't run the code

Tags: python-3.x

The code I had wasn't executing whatsoever. So, I tried it with a basic code:

```
x=10, if x==10:, print ("Hello"),
```

This worked. But the moment I extended it to anything else, it wouldn't run eg.:

```
count=0, x=10, if x==10:, count=count+1, if count == 10:, print ("Hello"),
```

(That had correct indents and exc. the commas.) The loop wouldn't loop.
Anyone understand why? The other queries similar to this regard a different issue. It won't run through CMDLine either. I did uninstall and reinstall it but that changed nothing.

Comment: Also count is 11 when it hits the if `statement`, so it never prints.

Comment: Python != MATLAB. You can't separate lines with commas as far as I am aware. Semicolons are OK though.

Comment: @madphysicist I was using it as,  for whatever reason,  I could get the lines to separate on here

Comment: I was using the comma to separate the lines as I couldn't get them to go to the next line

Answer (score 1):

The reason your loop won't run is because there isn't a loop. I think what you're trying to do is this.

```
for i in range(11):
    if i == 10:
        print('Hello')
```

With the current string of commands that you're running, `count` is simply being increment from `0` to `1`, and since `count != 10` at that point, you never see `Hello`.

Comment: I think OP meant conditional rather than loop, but that's just based on assumption.

Comment: @Jerrybibo perhaps, but regardless...if he's expecting to see `Hello` printed, then his logic is completely off.

Comment: Let's hope OP clarifies his question.

Comment: Yes, a loop is what I meant. But the problem arises with imported code,  that works at school with the same version,  doesn't work at home. Even if I type up an exact copy,  it fails to execute any part that would do so normally. As I said,  I have in installed and reinstalled Python 3.5 but no luck. Thanks

Comment: @CalFord are you using the same version of `python` at school and at home? I know a lot of education institutions still use `python2.7` because of stability.

Comment: Yeah,  we have just had tkinter added to the school drives along with it. I am pretty sure that it was updated as when we came back after a week of work experience, the teacher was happy we had the latest version.